# Pandas remove line break and convert text file to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split

I have a text file from which I want to remove the line break and add a header to convert it to a CSV file.

The file looks like this:

```
3G LOJISTIK VE HAVACILIK HIZMETLARI LTD., No. 3/182 Altintepe
Bagdat Cad. Istasyon Yolu Sok., Istanbul 34840, Turkey; Additional
Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [SDGT]
[IFSR] (Linked To: MAHAN AIR).

7 KARNES, Avenida Ciudad de Cali No. 15A-91, Local A06-07, Bogota,
Colombia; Matricula Mercantil No 1978075 (Colombia) [SDNTK].
```

The code i used :

```
sdnlist = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('sndlist.txt',delimiter="\t"))
sdnlist.to_csv('sdnlist.csv',index=False)
colnames=["a","b", "c", "d"]
sndlist_data = pd.read_csv("sdnlist.csv",names=colnames)
sndlist_data.head()
```

Desired output is simply splitting everything on commas: ( a,b,c.. ) are header names

```
  a        b            c        d         c           

3G LO...  No. 3/18.... Ista.... Turk..... Sancti... - Subject to....
```

Here is a sample from the text file in a pastbin [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/L1CYtF84)

The full text file is taken from the following link [FULL SDN TEXT](https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdnlist.txt)

Comment: Could you add what your desired output CSV would look like for that example. This would help show how you are trying to process it

Comment: Hey @MartinEvans the desired output CSV would be splitting on commas into fields just how normally how a CSV file is, I edited my original question with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Python's `itertools.groupby()` function to read whole blocks in at a time. This can then be processed to put it into a single line a split on what appears to be both commas and semicolons. A regular expression can locate commas inside parenthesises and replace it with a different character, e.g. `-`.

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv
import io
import re

with open('sdnlist.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(list('abcdefg'))
    
    for key, block in groupby(f_input, lambda x: x.strip() != ''):
        if key:
            single_line = ' '.join(block).replace('\n', '').replace(';', ',')
            single_line = re.sub('(\([^)]*?)(,)([^)]*?\))', r'\1-\3', single_line)
            row = next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(single_line), skipinitialspace=True))
            csv_output.writerow(row)
            #print('\n'.join(row) + '\n')
```

This should give you the following output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
3G LOJISTIK VE HAVACILIK HIZMETLARI LTD.,No. 3/182 Altintepe Bagdat Cad. Istasyon Yolu Sok.,Istanbul 34840,Turkey,Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [SDGT] [IFSR] (Linked To: MAHAN AIR).
7 KARNES,Avenida Ciudad de Cali No. 15A-91,Local A06-07,Bogota,Colombia,Matricula Mercantil No 1978075 (Colombia) [SDNTK].
7 MAKARA PHARY CO.,LTD.,Deaum Mien,Daeum Mien,Ta Khmau,Kandal 8252,Cambodia,Company Number 00037307 (Cambodia) [GLOMAG] (Linked To: SOPHARY- Kim).
7TH OF TIR (a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR COMPLEX- a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIAL COMPLEX,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES OF ISFAHAN/ESFAHAN,a.k.a. MOJTAMAE SANATE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SANAYE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SEVENTH OF TIR),Mobarakeh Road Km 45,Isfahan,Iran,P.O. Box 81465-478,Isfahan,Iran,Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [NPWMD] [IFSR].
7TH OF TIR COMPLEX (a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR- a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIAL COMPLEX,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES OF ISFAHAN/ESFAHAN,a.k.a. MOJTAMAE SANATE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SANAYE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SEVENTH OF TIR),Mobarakeh Road Km 45,Isfahan,Iran,P.O. Box 81465-478,Isfahan,Iran,Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [NPWMD] [IFSR].
7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIAL COMPLEX (a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR- a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR COMPLEX,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES OF ISFAHAN/ESFAHAN,a.k.a. MOJTAMAE SANATE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SANAYE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SEVENTH OF TIR),Mobarakeh Road Km 45,Isfahan,Iran,P.O. Box 81465-478,Isfahan,Iran,Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [NPWMD] [IFSR].
7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES (a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR- a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR COMPLEX,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIAL COMPLEX,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES OF ISFAHAN/ESFAHAN,a.k.a. MOJTAMAE SANATE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SANAYE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SEVENTH OF TIR),Mobarakeh Road Km 45,Isfahan,Iran,P.O. Box 81465-478,Isfahan,Iran,Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [NPWMD] [IFSR].
7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES OF ISFAHAN/ESFAHAN (a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR- a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR COMPLEX,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIAL COMPLEX,a.k.a. 7TH OF TIR INDUSTRIES,a.k.a. MOJTAMAE SANATE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SANAYE HAFTOME TIR,a.k.a. SEVENTH OF TIR),Mobarakeh Road Km 45,Isfahan,Iran,P.O. Box 81465-478,Isfahan,Iran,Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [NPWMD] [IFSR].
8TH IMAM INDUSTRIES GROUP (a.k.a. CRUISE MISSILE INDUSTRY GROUP- a.k.a. CRUISE SYSTEMS INDUSTRY GROUP,a.k.a. NAVAL DEFENCE MISSILE INDUSTRY GROUP,a.k.a. SAMEN AL-A'EMMEH INDUSTRIES GROUP),Tehran,Iran,Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [NPWMD] [IFSR].
"14 STAR SHIPPING MANAGEMENT (a.k.a. FOURTEEN STAR SHIPPING MANAGEMENT- a.k.a. ""FOURTEEN STARS"")",United Arab Emirates,Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [SDGT] (Linked To: MEHDI GROUP).
```

You will still struggle to pick out addresses.

Comment: Hey @MartinEvans thank you for your detailed answer some fields fit perfectly but others do not like for example this one `14 STAR SHIPPING MANAGEMENT (a.k.a. FOURTEEN STAR SHIPPING MANAGEMENT,"a.k.a. ""FOURTEEN STARS"")",United Arab Emirates,Additional Sanctions Information - Subject to Secondary Sanctions [SDGT] (Linked To: MEHDI GROUP).` is there a way to ignore the comma inside the `()` because the code splits on those also

Comment: Probably yes, but you would need to edit your question to include a few more example rows which have problems (and update your desired output to show exactly where the splits should be). As an alternative, you could use something like pastebin.com to post a link to the file.

Comment: I just added a sample from the text file in a Pastebin, along with a link to the full data

Comment: That data is definitely not easy to parse. You will still struggle to extract address columns. I have added code to remove commas inside parenthesises.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I was wondering if there is a way to automate this process for files that are similar to this one ( unstructured text files )

Comment: Not really, but it is good to keep various approaches to hand